# How to reduce SSR render time in next.js

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to reduce the load time that SSR is taking right now, So, I am building a product page and single product description page, but this time what is happending whenever I click on specific category, An API call is made and get the data and render that data, But Suppose I have 1000 product then It will take a lot of time to fetch and render data.

How can I reduce that time and user don't have to wait long enough for the product loading.

Current Code :

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { query } = context
  const { id, categoryId } = query

  var json ={
    _id : id
  }
  try{
    const respones = await fetch(Constants.getProducts, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      
      body: JSON.stringify(json),
      });
      const result = await respones.json();
      return{
          props : {result : result.doc[0], categoryId : categoryId , status : 200}
      }
  } catch(e){
    return{
      props : {result : result, categoryId : categoryId, status : 404}
  }
  }
}
```

Plz help

Comment: You should use `static generation`  with `incremental static generation` intead of SSR

Comment: If your API supports pagination, have you considered fetching fewer products during SSR, then fetching more as needed on the client-side?

Comment: Suppose I fetch 20 data but It still seems slow @juliomalves

Comment: If I use static generation then How new product data file will be generated? @IshanBassi

Comment: If it still slow even with fewer products then maybe the issue is in the API?

Comment: My api response is between 10-20ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **static generation** with `getStaticProps` and use **Incremental Static generation** for new products which are being added .

Next.js blog has an example that will help you.

Here is the Link:

[E-commerce Next.js App Example](https://vercel.com/blog/nextjs-server-side-rendering-vs-static-generation#e-commerce-next.js-app-example).

Read More about : [Incremental Static Generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration)